# How to deploy the Spring boot with angular2 code in heroku

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

How to deploy the Spring boot with angular2 code in heroku.. i have front end and back end code in different folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem)
If you want to deploy front and back ends together to Tomcat (for example), you should just create static folder in resources and transfer to it all your js code.

Comment: If i want to deploy my code in heroku , I have server and client web code how to deploy this code in heroku